# How is Task Manager showing a DLL as running process?

Tags: windows, task-manager

I've been working with windows for almost 20 years, but I have never seen something like this. On a Windows 10 Machine, there is a .dll listed as separate process in task manager. It has Network connectivity, handles and everything that usually only executables have. Can someone tell me how this works?

I noticed this when I wanted to block network traffic for this application. But firewall Software only allows executables to be selected for blocking, no dlls.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/CPoA5x7]